# Associated References types as Value Types

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types, rust-diesel

This is a [trait found in Diesel](https://docs.rs/diesel/0.16.0/diesel/associations/trait.Identifiable.html).

```
trait Identifiable {
    type Id;
    ...
}
```

This is a User model with derived impl of `Identifiable`.

```
#[derive(Identifiable)]
pub struct User {
    id: i32,
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
}
```

As per the docs, implementation of Identifiable is derived on the reference of the struct i.e. on `&User`. 
This is a trait to `find` with `id` defined on the `Identifiable`. The implementation on a User would be as follows.

```
trait Find<'a>: Sized where
    &'a Self: Identifiable,
    Self: 'a,
{
    fn find(id: <&'a Self as Identifiable>::Id) -> Result<Self, MyError>;
}
```

The impl of `Find` on a `User`.

```
impl<'a> Find<'a> for User {
    fn find(id: i32) -> Result<User, MyError> {
        let conn = ::establish_conn()?;
        Ok(users::table.find(id).get_result(&conn)?)
    }
}
```

The error on compilation:

```
    fn find(id: i32) -> Result<Self> {
                ^^^ expected &i32, found i32
```

As I would like to find a user with an `i32`, the impl `<&'a Self as Identifiable>::Id` would refer to the id as `&i32`.
I only want `id` to be a value not a reference type.

How can I define the type of `id` on `find` to be a value type when `Identifiable` is applied for reference type `&User`?

Comment: *I only want id to be a value not a reference type.* — **why**? It basically shouldn't matter to you if `Id` resolves to a `u8` or a `String` or a `&str`.

Comment: But `Id` in my case in not a `String` but an `i32`. Writing `&num` for the `find` is just not worth it. I have to dereference it again within the method  to use it.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]. As it stands, your question isn't understandable or is missing important information. If there's an implementation of `Identifiable` where `Type` is `i32`, then it doesn't matter that you are taking `<&'a Self as Identifiable>::Id`; it will **be** an `i32` — you don't have a reference. If you are making it generic, you can't avoid it.

Comment: *the `impl <&'a Self as Identifiable>::Id` would refer to the id as `&i32`* — [no, it wouldn't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=adb17ce2557323abd9ae80ebb0850f19&version=nightly). It will still be whatever type `Id` is. **Please** create a MCVE that shows the problem you are having. Don't have "..." pieces, make it **complete**. Show the **full** error message you are getting.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the whole problem. Should have put the error message from the beginning. The example you wrote worked for me as expected. Has the `Id` been derived as a reference from the beginning in diesel?